# How to retrieve json file from Twiter Search API with CURL using urllib library

Tags: python, api, curl, twitter, urllib

I just learnt how to access data thru application API and I stumble to a trouble.
I am currently trying to retrieve json file from Twitter Search API. The documentation of the API says CURL is used in order to access the data through HTTP GET. Below is the curl format:

```
curl  "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/:product/:label.json?query=TwitterDev%20%5C%22search%20api%5C%22&maxResults=500&fromDate=<yyyymmddhhmm>&toDate=<yyyymmddhhmm>" -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN"
```

-[curl api format](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search)

I have already tried to access it using urllib but still got error message during the run.

**Below is the code I used.**

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import twurl
import ssl
import json

#TWITTER_URL = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'
TWITTER_URL = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/30day/data1.json'

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

while True:
    #acct = input('Enter Twitter Account: ')    
    #if (len(acct) < 1): break
    parameters = {
            #'screen_name': acct, 
            #'COunT': '3',
            'query': 'inline skate',
            'fromDate': '201906010000',
            'toDate': '201906102359',
            'maxResults': '20',
            }

    url = twurl.augment(TWITTER_URL, parameters)
    print('\nRetrieving', url, '\n')

    connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
    data = connection.read().decode()
    js = json.loads(data)
    jsdmp = json.dumps(js, indent=2)
    print(jsdmp, '\n')

    #for data in js:
        #print(data['text'])

    headers = dict(connection.getheaders())
    print('\nRemaining', headers['x-rate-limit-remaining'], '\n')
    break
```

**Here's the error message I keep getting:**

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Unprocessable Entity
```

It works when I try to access user_timeline tweets retriever above

```
TWITTER_URL = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'
```

But it doesn't with the search API I guess it is because of the CURL.
I already check the parameter I use is necessary as the docs tell to use.

Also, the *twurl* library used to access the token and process the url and parameters simultaneously to produce final url. (as far as I understand)

**Below is the twurl code:**

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import oauth
import hidden

# https://apps.twitter.com/
# Create App and get the four strings, put them in hidden.py

def augment(url, parameters):
    secrets = hidden.oauth()
    consumer = oauth.OAuthConsumer(secrets['consumer_key'], secrets['consumer_secret'])
    token = oauth.OAuthToken(secrets['token_key'], secrets['token_secret'])

    oauth_request = oauth.OAuthRequest.from_consumer_and_token(consumer,
                    token, http_method='GET', http_url=url,
                    parameters=parameters)
    #below is the main function galls!!
    oauth_request.sign_request(oauth.OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(),
                               consumer, token)
    return oauth_request.to_url()
```

**Below is hidden, where all the key and token stored:**

```
def oauth():
    return {"consumer_key": "2HZq407wF.................",
            "consumer_secret": "OsemLubDmCcQq5Y3q............",
            "token_key": "75230340-2SGPJWWn..............",
            "token_secret": "NZcII332Y3EI.............."}
```

I have looked for solution and most of them seem to use urllib2 for CURL which I dont think is compatible with python 3?
Do you have any suggestion? I kind of stuck in this step and not going anywhere.

Thanks yall